# PHP function to go to the next cycle of the loop?

Tags: php, loops

I am looking for a a function that will allow me to go to the next loop cycle.

so for instance:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($something)) {
    if ($row['ID'] == "1") {
        goToNextCycle;
    }
    doFunction1();
    doFunction2();
}
```

The function that i'm looking for should replace `goToNextCycle`, and it should not run `doFunction1` and `doFunction2` when `$row['ID'] == "1'` but instead continue the while loop for the next value.

Is there any function that does that?

Thanks.

Comment: Hmmm, "continue the while loop"... "**continue** the while loop"... "**`continue;`** the while loop"... ;-P

Answer (score 14, accepted):

using `continue;`  this is what you [need](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php)

one additional great thing in php, is that the continue accepts an optional numeric argument which tells it how many levels of 
enclosing loops it should skip to the end of. 
so you can write in your loop something like `continue 2;`

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

```
$ok=false;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($something) && (!$ok)) {
    if ($row['ID'] == "1") {
        $ok = true;
        goToNextCycle;
    }else{
        doFunction1();
        doFunction2();
    }
}
```